# How can I remove the rownames in a data.frame that I want to export like a png?

Tags: r, dataframe, png

I'm trying to export a table into a png but in the left part R put the rownames or rownumbers, I need remove that numbers in the png file. Somebody can help me please?

```
png("tabla.png",width =  700,height = 750)
grid.table(Tabla_1)
dev.off()
```

Comment: rownames(Tabla_1) <- c()

Comment: `rownames(Tabla_1) <- NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the gtable option as described in [this link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/tableGrob.html): 
rows = NULL in tableGrob will remove the names.

```
tableGrob(iris[1:4, 1:3], cols = NULL, rows=NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks you give me the idea, I use grid.table(Tabla_1, rows = NULL)